# Is it possible to use winmerge to view git diffs from cygwin?

Tags: windows, git, windows-xp, cygwin, winmerge

I like to use git on cygwin, but the only downside I have is when I want to `git difftool` I cannot use anything useful. `git diff` is fine for me most of the time, but sometimes I'd like to use winmerge to view these diffs via `git difftool` is there some way to set this up?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/255202/how-do-i-view-git-diff-output-with-visual-diff-program is a good start for that kind of feature.

Comment: Note: to be tested in cygwin, but [Git 2.5 is now aware of Winmerge as a diff or merge tool](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30699239/6309)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For cygwin, the SO question "[How can I configure Mercurial to use WinMerge for merges, under cygwin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/548520/how-can-i-configure-mercurial-to-use-winmerge-for-merges-under-cygwin)" can be applied to git (when combining the following winmerge script with the older question "[use Winmerge inside of Git to file diff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1881594/use-winmerge-inside-of-git-to-file-diff)")

```
#!/bin/sh
"/cygdrive/c/Program Files/WinMerge/WinMergeU.EXE" /e /ub /dl other /dr local `cygpath -aw $1` `cygpath -aw $2` `cygpath -aw $3`
```

---

### Process

You have more details in this article "[Git + WinMerge + Cygwin](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/83230/Git-plus-WinMerge-plus-Cygwin.aspx)" (from [Thiru Thirunavukarasu](http://www.codeproject.com/script/Membership/View.aspx?mid=4900650)):
(but I would still recommend the `WinMergeU.exe` options from above)

> Add the following lines to your .gitconfig file:

```
  [diff]
    tool = winmerge
  [difftool "winmerge"]
    cmd = git-difftool-winmerge-wrapper.sh \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\"
  [difftool]
    prompt = false
```

> The last option (`prompt = false`) is optional. You can omit it if you do want Git to prompt you before opening each diff.
>
> Create a file named **`git-difftool-winmerge-wrapper.sh`** and place it in your path.
>   I just dropped it in my home directory. You can change the default Cygwin path to include your home directory by modifying the .bash_profile file (also in your home directory) and adding `PATH=${PATH}:${HOME}`
>
> Add the following to `git-difftool-winmerge-wrapper.sh`:

```
  #!/bin/sh
  echo "Launching WinMergeU.exe \"$(cygpath -aw "$1")\" \"$(cygpath -aw "$2")\""
  if [ -f "$1" -a -f "$2" ]
  then
    "C:/Program Files (x86)/WinMerge/WinMergeU.exe" -e -u -wl -dl "Base" -dr "Mine" "$(cygpath -aw "$1")" "$(cygpath -aw "$2")"
  else
    echo "skipping as one file doesn't exist"
  fi
```

(again, do some testing with those WinMerge options)

---

### Scripts

If you want to go "all WinMerge", both for diff and merge git functions, you have this [gist page to follow](https://gist.github.com/509918) from [ecerulm (Ruben Laguna)](https://github.com/ecerulm):

> #### `diffmerge-diff.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh
# Use SourceGear DiffMerge as mergetool for git in cygwin.
#   git config --global mergetool.diffmerge.cmd "diffmergetool.sh \"\$LOCAL\" \"\$REMOTE\" \"\$BASE\" \"\$MERGED\""
#   git config --global mergetool.diffmerge.trustExitCode false
#   git difftool -t diffmerge branch1..branch2

# Reference: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/abs-guide.pdf

library=githelperfunctions.sh

#[ -f $library ] && . $library
. $library

echo Launching DiffMerge.exe - diffmerge-diff.sh: 

set_path_vars "$1" "$2" "$3" "$4"

echo "$diffmergewinpath" -t1=FROM_VERSION -t2=TO_VERSION --caption=$caption $localwinpath $remotewinpath
"$diffmergewinpath" -t1=FROM_VERSION -t2=TO_VERSION --caption="$caption" "$localwinpath" "$remotewinpath"
```

> #### `diffmerge-merge.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh
# Use SourceGear DiffMerge as mergetool for git in cygwin.
#   git config --global mergetool.diffmerge.cmd "diffmergetool.sh \"\$LOCAL\" \"\$REMOTE\" \"\$BASE\" \"\$MERGED\""
#   git config --global mergetool.diffmerge.trustExitCode false
#   git mergetool -t diffmerge

# Reference: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/abs-guide.pdf

library=githelperfunctions.sh

#[ -f $library ] && . $library
. $library

echo Launching DiffMerge.exe - diffmerge-merge.sh: 

set_path_vars "$1" "$2" "$3" "$4"

"$diffmergewinpath" --merge -t1=FROM_VERSION -t2=MERGED -t3=TO_VERSION --result="$mergedwinpath" --caption="$caption" "$localwinpath" "$basewinpath" "$remotewinpath"

unix2dos "$merged"
```

> #### `githelperfunctions.sh`

```
# Helper functions


convert_path () {
    file=$1

    if [ "$file" == '/dev/null' ] || [ ! -e "$file" ]
        then 
           file="/tmp/nulla"
           `echo "">$file`
    fi
    echo `cygpath -w -a "$file"`
}


set_path_vars () {
    local=$1
    remote=$2
    base=$3
    merged=$4

    echo ========= Cygwin paths =======
    echo "LOCAL   :  $local"
    echo "REMOTE  :  $remote"
    echo "BASE    :  $base"
    echo "MERGED  :  $merged"

    localwinpath=$(convert_path "$local")
    remotewinpath=$(convert_path "$remote")
    basewinpath=$(convert_path "$base")
    mergedwinpath=$(convert_path "$merged")

    echo ========= Win paths =======
    echo "LOCAL   :  $localwinpath"
    echo "REMOTE  :  $remotewinpath"
    echo "BASE    :  $basewinpath"
    echo "MERGED  :  $mergedwinpath"

    caption=`basename "$merged"`
    diffmergewinpath="C:/Program Files/SourceGear/DiffMerge/DiffMerge.exe"
    winmergewinpath="C:/Program Files/WinMerge/WinMergeU.exe"
#   diffmergewinpath=`cygpath -u C:/Program Files/SourceGear/DiffMerge/DiffMerge.exe`
#   winmergewinpath=`cygpath -u \"C:\Program Files\WinMerge\WinMergeU.exe\"`
}
```

> #### `winmerge-diff.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh
# Use winmerge as mergetool for git in cygwin.
#   git config --global difftool.winmerge.cmd "winmerge-diff.sh \"\$LOCAL\" \"\$REMOTE\" \"\$BASE\""
#   git config --global mergetool.winmerge.trustExitCode false
#   git difftool -t winmerge branch1..branch2   

# Reference: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/abs-guide.pdf
# Reference: http://winmerge.org/docs/manual/CommandLine.html


library=githelperfunctions.sh

#[ -f $library ] && . $library
. $library

echo Launching winmerge.exe - winmerge-diff.sh: 

set_path_vars "$1" "$2" "$3" "$4"

"$winmergewinpath" /dl "LOCAL.$caption" /dr "TO_VERSION.$caption" "$localwinpath" "$remotewinpath"
```

> #### `winmerge-merge.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh
# Use winmerge as mergetool for git in cygwin.
#   git config --global mergetool.winmerge.cmd "winmerge-merge.sh \"\$LOCAL\" \"\$REMOTE\" \"\$BASE\" \"\$MERGED\""
#   git config --global mergetool.winmerge.trustExitCode false
#   git mergetool -t diffmerge

# Reference: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/abs-guide.pdf
# Reference: http://winmerge.org/docs/manual/CommandLine.html

library=githelperfunctions.sh

#[ -f $library ] && . $library
. $library

echo Launching winmerge.exe - winmerge-merge.sh: 


set_path_vars "$1" "$2" "$3" "$4"

# -- use WinMergeU conflictFile
"$winmergewinpath" "$mergedwinpath"
```

Comment: As a result of some spaces in my folder structures, I had to alter the if test in the the git-difftool-winmerge-wrapper.sh to `if [ -f "$1" -a -f "$2" ]` or the test would fail; unsure if this is version specific.

Comment: @Chris Thank you. I have edited the answer accordingly.