# Problem with git + DiffMerge on OS X

Tags: git, macos, diffmerge

I have configured Sourcegear DiffMerge to be my default git merge tool using the following instructions:

```
git config --global diff.tool diffmerge
git config --global difftool.diffmerge.cmd "diffmerge \"\$LOCAL\" \"\$REMOTE\""

git config --global merge.tool diffmerge
git config --global mergetool.diffmerge.cmd "diffmerge --merge --result=\"\$MERGED\"
\"\$LOCAL\" \"\$BASE\" \"\$REMOTE\""
git config --global mergetool.diffmerge.trustexitcode false
```

Source: http://www.andrejkoelewijn.com/wp/2010/01/08/configure-diffmerge-with-git/

However when I run `git mergetool` I get the following error:

[image: DiffMerge Error]

What could be the cause of this issue?

Comment: Would having an intermediate script help? As in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3780420/is-it-possible-to-use-winmerge-to-view-git-diffs-from-cygwin/4314057#4314057

Comment: are you able to run the diffmerge command in a terminal outside of using git?

Comment: I see the same thing. The BASE file does not exist on the local filesystem, but the other files referenced in the diffmerge commandline (in your case, 10new.xml.REMOTE.2128.xml and 10new.xml.LOCAL.2128.xml) do exist. An issue with DiffMerge's expectations of Git behaviour (possibly Git version behaviour)?

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this, what version of Git and Diffmerge do you have?  I have git version 1.7.3.4, DiffMerge 3.3.0 (1001)

Answer (score 8):

It is possible that there will be no `$BASE` file, if for instance the two files being merged have no common ancestor, or if you happen to get the conflict when applying or rebasing a patch rather than merging branches. In this case, while the `$BASE` variable will still be set, there will be no file there.

In your mergetool command, you need to check whether `$BASE` exists, and do a merge without a common ancestor if it does not. It doesn't look like DiffMerge supports that mode (it supports merging two files with no common ancestor, but it always writes the output to one of the files, not a result file). Instead, you'll need instead to pass in `$LOCAL` as the `$BASE` file if `$BASE` does not exist:

```
git config --global mergetool.diffmerge.cmd 'diffmerge --merge --result="$MERGED" "$LOCAL" "$(if test -f "$BASE"; then echo "$BASE"; else echo "$LOCAL"; fi)" "$REMOTE"'
```

Comment: Wow awesome, looks like the only other option is to use the paid Git mergetools.  Works great, thanks.

Comment: Awesome tip Brian! I've incorporated it into my Git/DiffMerge setup HOWTO: http://twobitlabs.com/2011/08/install-diffmerge-git-mac-os-x/