# git with DiffMerge setup to mimic Mercurials setup with diffmerge

Tags: git, mercurial, diffmerge

I'm wondering if there is a way to setup git and diffmerge so that when you execute the following command: `git difftool` diffmerge pops up and shows you a file listing of all the modified files instead of cycling through them via the command-line?

I'm thinking it must be some setting the ~/.gitconfig file. Here is my current ~/.gitconfig:

```
[merge]
    tool = diffmerge
[mergetool "diffmerge"]
    cmd = /Applications/DiffMerge.app/Contents/MacOS/diffmerge --merge --result=$MERGED $LOCAL $BASE $REMOTE
[mergetool]
    keepBackup = false
[diff]
    tool = diffmerge
[difftool "diffmerge"]
    cmd = /Applications/DiffMerge.app/Contents/MacOS/diffmerge $LOCAL $REMOTE
```

See below for Mercurials (HG) way of presenting DiffMerge.
[image: Mercurial's way of diffmerge]

Comment: I think what I'm looking for is the "folder diffs" that Mercurial and DiffMerge allows, and for some reason git doesn't, or I don't know how to set that up.

Answer (score 1):

You should have the following lines in your `.gitconfig`:

```
[diff]
    tool = diffmerge
[difftool "diffmerge"]
    cmd = /Applications/DiffMerge.app/Contents/MacOS/DiffMerge \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\"
```

Answer (score 1):

Git does not provide directory diffs in its default setup.  See this related SO question:

> [git difftool, open all diff files immediately, not in serial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1220309/git-difftool-open-all-diff-files-immediately-not-in-serial)

Also, see the [git diffall](https://github.com/thenigan/git-diffall) project on GitHub which implements this feature as an add-on script.

Comment: Perfect. This is exactly what I was looking for. Its too bad git doesn't inherently handle folder diffs.

Answer (score 1):

Note that you now can ([git 1.7.11](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.linux.kernel/1307164)) diff directories (ie display all the files to be compared, before opening the difftool)

See "[`git difftool` to give directory compare?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2115188/6309)"

In other words, git now *does* "inherently handle folder diffs."

Comment: How will that work with a 3 way merge tool such as DiffMerge?

Comment: @Bryan `git diff` and `difftool` are about two-way diffs (as mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7251477/git-diff-whats-the-difference-between-having-and-no-dots and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635788/doing-a-three-way-compare-with-git-and-kdiff3). That option won't concern `mergetool`, which will show a three-way diff, but without using the `difftool` setting (hence ignoring the new `difftool` option `--dir-diff`).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the question and answer here for details regarding setting up git with diffmerge:

[Problem with git + DiffMerge on OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4439268/problem-with-git-diffmerge-on-os-x)